# terminal starts with `no such file or directory` message

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I removed Enthought Canopy from my Mac and now when I start terminal there's this warning message says

```
-bash: /Users/myname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/myname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

of course they don't exist because I deleted the program. How do I remove the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your profile (.profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, .tcshrc, etc… that is appropriate for your chosen shell) and remove any lines that contain "Enthought". It might be a bit more complicated than just deleting a couple of lines depending on what it did to your login file.

Comment: Thank you! It's actually written here https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy